# Update an entire row in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table object in R that has 9,000 columns.  My code calculates new values for all 9,000 columns at once and returns a vector of values.  I'd like to just replace the row in the data.table with all the values at once.  In a dataFrame object this is easy.  However, I can't figure out how to get that working in a data.table.

```
d <- data.table(q=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
d[q==1, := c(5,5,5,5)] # FAILS
d[q==1, ] <- c(5,5,5,5) # FAILS
```

Any idea how to efficiently update the whole row at once?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `names(d)` for LHS, then use `as.list` in order to convert your vector to a list so `data.table` will understand that it need to assign *each* value to a *different* column instead *all* the values to *each* column.

You are also converting `character` vector to `numeric` here (the `x` column), so `data.table` will return a warning in order to make sure you are aware of that.

```
vec <- c(5, 5, 5, 5)
d[q == 1L, names(d) := as.list(vec)][]
#    q x y v
# 1: 5 5 5 5
# 2: 2 a 3 2
# 3: 3 a 6 3
# 4: 4 b 1 4
# 5: 5 b 3 5
# 6: 6 b 6 6
# 7: 7 c 1 7
# 8: 8 c 3 8
# 9: 9 c 6 9
```

Answer (score 6):

This can also be done using `set`, for the example above (referencing by row number).

```
set(d, 1L, names(d), as.list(vec))
```

You *may* gain some speed using `set` instead, but lose some of the advantage if you need to retrieve the row numbers first.

```
# Create large data table
DT = data.table(col1 = 1:1e5)
cols = paste0('col', 1:9e3)
for (col in cols){ DT[, (col) := 1:1e5] }
vec <- rep(5,9e3)

# Test options
microbenchmark(
  row_idnx <- DT[,.I[col1 == 1L]], # Retrieve row number
  set(DT, row_idnx, names(DT), as.list(vec)),
  DT[col1 == 1L, names(DT) := as.list(vec)]
)

Unit: microseconds
                                          expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
              row_idnx <- DT[, .I[col1 == 1L]] 1255.430 1969.5630 2168.9744 2129.2635 2302.1000  3269.947   100
    set(DT, row_idnx, names(DT), as.list(vec))  171.606  207.3235  323.7642  236.6765  274.6515  7725.120   100
 DT[col1 == 1L, `:=`(names(DT), as.list(vec))] 2761.289 2998.3750 3361.7842 3155.8165 3444.6310 13473.081   100
```